# SMTP Module not sending email

Tags: 8, emails

Using XAMPP on Mac

I have installed https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp

After setting up **admin/config/system/smtp**

[image]

It gives above error. Unable to send test email.

Do we have to any setting on gmail or i'm missing anything?

Comment: Select "Enable debugging" at the bottom of the settings page and include the result in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to be auth to be able to send mail from gmail's SMTP (smtp user/ smtp password).
Moreover, you have to "allow" the sender's email in your google account.

theMailYouSendFrom@whatever.com have to be allowed to send mail with account yourAccount@gmail.com; somewhere in gmail's parameters, you can validate this mail.

I remember there is a limit, 450 mails/day for each google account (this could have change now, that was 3 or 4 years ago), and more with payed gapps.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error on 8.7.1 and smtp 8.x-1.0-beta4 version.

Followed the steps provided in the below link will solve the issue.

https://stevepolito.design/blog/drupal-configure-smtp-module-work-gmail-updated/

Answer (score 0):

Check settings.php for overwritten SMTP settings.

Answer (score 0):

try to use
port 587 for gmail.
Use encrypted protocol 'TLS'.
Enable TLS encryption automatically On.
Timeout 300.

this configuration is working fine for me